# Cannot connect to remote desktop that has been idle for a while

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, router, remote-desktop

I am trying to connect to a laptop that is connected to the same LAN via WiFi from a desktop that is connected via ethernet. It usually works but connection fails the laptop has been idle for some time. My workaround is to disconnect and reconnect to the wifi on the laptop.

Is there some configuration I can do on the laptop or perhaps the router that would make the remote desktop services on the laptop always respond? I am connecting to the computer name. ipv6 is disabled on the network adapters. Both machines are running Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off sleep mode in windows on the remote connect pc or turn on wake on lan.

How to:

- Windows key + X
- Select device manager
- expand Network adapter

[image]

- Then select the Power Management tab and check off all three boxes
  shown below.
  [image]
- Next, select the Advanced tab, scroll down in the Property box and
  select Wake on Magic Packet and ensure that it is enabled in the
  Value list box then click OK.

[image]

You may also need to configure wake on Lan or Wake on wlan in your router for the specific mac address if this still does not work